# How can I position images so that they overlap a table using html?

Tags: html, position, overlap

I have an image floated right of text, and a table beneath the text. However, the table is pushed down by the image. How can I organise the table so that it appears beneath the text without affecting the image placement?

I have attempted using relative and absolute divs, but have not found a satisfactory answer.

```html
<img src="https://www.myrfs.nsw.gov.au/portals/0/beyondblue.png" style="float: right; padding-left: 5px">
    <h3>beyondblue</h3>
    <p>beyondblue provides information and support to help everyone in Australia achieve their best possible mental health, whatever their age and wherever they live.</p>
    <table style="width: 0px;">
    <colgroup><col><col></colgroup>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Website</b></td>
            <td><a href="http://www.beyondblue.org.au ">www.beyondblue.org.au</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Phone numbers</b></td>
            <td><p><b>Support</b>: <a href="tel:1300224636">1300 22 46 36</a>
            <br><b>Lifeline</b>: <a href="tel:131114">13 11 14</a>
            <br><b>Suicide Callback Service</b>: <a href="tel:1300659467">1300 659 467</a></p>
            <p>If you are in an emergency or at immediate risk of harm to yourself or others, please contact emergency services on <a href="tel:000">Triple Zero (000)</a>.</p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Other services</b></td>
            <td>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="https://www.beyondblue.org.au/get-support/get-immediate-support" target="_blank">Online chat</a></li>
                <li><a href="www.facebook.com/beyondblue" target="_blank">Facebook</a></li>
            </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: I should add, I need the resolution to have a result that is relative to the image placement, and not an absolute position, as this page is updated on occasions by users unfamiliar with html code (they use a WYSIWYG).

Answer (score 0):

is this is how you want it?

```css
.overlap{
    position: absolute;
    top:20px;
    left:20px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.myrfs.nsw.gov.au/portals/0/beyondblue.png" style="float: right; padding-left: 5px">
<div class="overlap">
<h3>beyondblue</h3>
<p>beyondblue provides information and support to help everyone in Australia achieve their best possible mental health, whatever their age and wherever they live.</p>
<table style="width: 0px;">
<colgroup><col><col></colgroup>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><b>Website</b></td>
        <td><a href="http://www.beyondblue.org.au ">www.beyondblue.org.au</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><b>Phone numbers</b></td>
        <td><p><b>Support</b>: <a href="tel:1300224636">1300 22 46 36</a>
        <br><b>Lifeline</b>: <a href="tel:131114">13 11 14</a>
        <br><b>Suicide Callback Service</b>: <a href="tel:1300659467">1300 659 467</a></p>
        <p>If you are in an emergency or at immediate risk of harm to yourself or others, please contact emergency services on <a href="tel:000">Triple Zero (000)</a>.</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><b>Other services</b></td>
        <td>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="https://www.beyondblue.org.au/get-support/get-immediate-support" target="_blank">Online chat</a></li>
            <li><a href="www.facebook.com/beyondblue" target="_blank">Facebook</a></li>
        </ul>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: I changed the position to relative, and this has provided the desired result.

Comment: I also moved the div tag so that the initial <p> text did not overlap the image.

Answer (score 0):

I added style css, changed the position to relative and a `<div>` tag to produce the desired result:

```
<style>
    .overlap{
    position: relative;
    top: -60px
 }
</style>

<img src="https://www.myrfs.nsw.gov.au/portals/0/beyondblue.png" style="float: right; padding-left: 5px">
<h3>beyondblue</h3>
<p>beyondblue provides information and support to help everyone in Australia achieve their best possible mental health, whatever their age and wherever they live.</p>
<div class="overlap">
<table style="width: 0px;">
<colgroup><col><col></colgroup>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><b>Website</b></td>
        <td><a href="http://www.beyondblue.org.au ">www.beyondblue.org.au</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><b>Phone numbers</b></td>
        <td><p><b>Support</b>: <a href="tel:1300224636">1300 22 46 36</a>
        <br><b>Lifeline</b>: <a href="tel:131114">13 11 14</a>
        <br><b>Suicide Callback Service</b>: <a href="tel:1300659467">1300 659 467</a></p>
        <p>If you are in an emergency or at immediate risk of harm to yourself or others, please contact emergency services on <a href="tel:000">Triple Zero (000)</a>.</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><b>Other services</b></td>
        <td>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="https://www.beyondblue.org.au/get-support/get-immediate-support" target="_blank">Online chat</a></li>
            <li><a href="www.facebook.com/beyondblue" target="_blank">Facebook</a></li>
        </ul>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```